# Bit Shifting a Byte

Tags: java, byte, bit

I have the following code:

```
byte my_byte;   
my_byte |= (1 << 7);
my_byte |= (1 << 6);
```

I am trying to set the 8th and 7th bit in my_byte to 1. Using the debugger I found that after executing the 1st line, the value of my_byte is -128. After executing the 2nd line, the value of my_byte is -64.

I thought the final result would have been 192 (2^7 + 2^6). Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Also, should I be initializing my_byte at the start? If so, how do I just set all the bits to 0?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `byte` is signed, so `10000000` is translated (2's-complement) to -128. Use `short` instead of `byte`.
To init all the bits to 0 just do `short my_byte = 0;`

P.s : short is 16-bit unlike byte which is 8 bit, AFAIK there is no 8-bit unsigned primitive type in Java

Comment: A `char`, being the only unsigned integer quantity in Java, is also a great option.